# c++. не работает getline

Tags: c++, getline

программа не компилируется. getline в visual studio подчеркнута красным, помогите пожалуйста

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");     

    ofstream textfile("text1.txt");
    textfile << "Hi++!";
    textfile.close();

    char text[50];

    ifstream textfile("text1.txt");
    if (!textfile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Erorr! File is not found" << endl;
    }
    else {
        
        textfile.getline(text, 50);
        textfile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что ваш исходный код не компилируется. Далее — что вы понимаете под "не работает"? В чем это проявляется? Как вы это определили? Если немного подправить ваш файл — изменить имя одной переменной — то все работает...

Comment: тем, что во первых он не компилируется (прога), а во вторых, getline подчеркнута красным и написана что она типо не входит в класс fstream: 
класс не содержит члена

Comment: ifstream textfileIn("text1.txt"); имя другое надо дать для чтения

Comment: Естественно не компилируется! если вы напишете `int t; double t;` — будет это компилироваться? Нет. Потому что разные переменные имеют одно имя. Но вы же не будете говорить, что проблема в операторе `+`, например :) У вас примерно то же самое, что "не могу перевезти мешок картошки в багажнике", а потом выясняется, что у вас два колеса сняты...

Comment: @enterproggramming Помечайте как правильный ответ и закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кусок кода измените

```
ifstream textfileIn("text1.txt");
if (!textfileIn.is_open()) {
    cout << "Error! File is not found" << endl;
}
else {
    
    textfileIn.getline(text, 50);
    textfileIn.close();
}
```

Comment: Помечайте как ответ и закрывайте вопрос